# Refresh timer on self-destruct div setTimeout(function(){...},3000);

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

So I have this [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/jcv51u73/1/) which adds a div at the bottom right corner to notify the user when he adds an item (click event on `item1`..`item5` divs). This div self-destructs (`div.remove()`) after a few seconds.

```
$(document.body).append(element); //the div created

setTimeout(function(){
      $('#test').remove(); //the div to be removed
}, 3000);
```

The first problem was that adding several divs in less than 3 seconds would result in a lot of divs not being able to see the ones underneath. So I added this line on the `.click()` event before doing anything else happens.

> $('#test').remove();

**The new/current problem** is that adding several divs in less than 3 seconds might result in the div appearing for only a second or less, not being able to see what it is. Is there a way to fix this??

Comment: +1 for asking question in very clear way.

Comment: I don't think the question is at all clear - it only made sense to me after looking at the fiddle.

Comment: @Alnitak as not a native English speaker I tried to do my best :P

Comment: Don't worry - I've seen worse.  I'd also suggest you take a good look at my answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clear the timeout before starting a new one, but more than that I would suggest encapsulating the desired behaviour of the popup elsewhere so that it's not tied to the `click` function:

```
function Popup() {
    var timer = null;
    var $el = $('<div>', {
        id: 'test',
        class: 'arrow_box'
    }).appendTo(document.body).hide();

    this.show = function (text) {
        $el.text(text).stop(true, true).show();
        clearTimeout(timer);
        timer = setTimeout(function () {
            $el.hide('slow');
        }, 3000);
    }
}

var popup = new Popup();
$('.item ').on('click', function () {
    popup.show('You just added an '+ $(this).text() + '!');
});
```

Note that leaving the element in the DOM (but hidden) allows more flexibility with animations - e.g. you can make the popup fadeout instead of simply blink out of existence.

Demo at http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/4et4cctr/

Comment: Thanks for your time and answer too :D A more elegant one I would say but in this case I prefer code simplicity instead :D

Comment: @Alexandros in the longer term, this will be simpler, believe me!  What happens, for example, if you want to have more actions on the page that trigger the popup?  With the other answer that wouldn't work.

Comment: I will keep it in mind :D Maybe when I learn more I will be able to see what you mean

Comment: In the end I decided to mark your answer as the correct one because you found a flaw in the previous one!

Comment: @Alexandros Thanks :)  BTW - I've made a minor edit - adding `.stop(true, true)` to ensure that popups reappear immediately if the disappear animation is still ongoing.

Comment: FWIW, it would be trivial to add a `.hide` method to `Popup` if you wanted to manually force it to disappear.

Comment: its fine just how it is :D - perhaps in the future!

Answer (score 1):

Try this : store time interval in a variable and clear it on every click of `item`, so that previously set interval for `#test` will get clear and new interval get set using `setTimeout`

```
var timer;//variable to store timeout
$('.item').click(function() {
    $('#test').remove();
    window.clearTimeout(timer);//clear timeout
    var element = "<div id='test' class='arrow_box'>You just added an "+$(this).text()+"!</div> ";

    $(document.body).append(element);
    //store timeout
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
      $('#test').remove();
    }, 3000);
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/jcv51u73/4/)**

Comment: Thanks right to the point! knew I should clear the time oute and create a new one somehow just didn't know the how :D